# Flutter memory leak - DevTools Does not show entries under Filtered

Tags: flutter

I have a memory leak in my flutter application. I took a memory snapshot a couple minutes apart using Flutter DevTools.

I saw that under the filtered tree branch the memory had increased.

However, when I expand the filtered treeview the children are the exact same between the two snapshots and it seems like the full amount of memory shown in the parent are not represented by the children.

I was wondering why this might be and if anyone would have any techniques as to how to identify where the extra memory is for the filtered node.

[image]